# Ganache Issue-Not showing the available networks

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

Iam trying to connect Ganache in mac, when i started Ganache ,its not showing the available accounts and open the server screen - unable to select the host name. It has only one option "hostname of the server 0.0.0.0 - All Interfaces."

I've tried

Restarting Ganache,
Restarting Computer,
Uninstalling from Applications and Reinstalling,
Ganache Downloaded Ganache from
[https://trufflesuite.com/ganache/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYfWd.png)

FYI:i have installed truffle suite
Truffle v5.5.20 (core: 5.5.20)
Ganache v7.2.0
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v16.15.1
Web3.js v1.7.4

[image]

Anyone has idea how resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance
Laxmi

Answer (score 0):

your `truffle.config.js` should have this minimum configuration to connect

```
module.exports = {
  contracts_build_directory: "./public/contracts",
  networks: {
    development: {
      // in hte truffle HOSTNAME down set the correct host. "0.0.0.0" should accept this
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*",
    },
  },

  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.13",
    },
  },
```

If ganache is running, when you start your truffle project it should automatically connect

Comment: Hi Yilmaz, Thanks for the answer but the problem is unable to run Ganache and when  i start/deploy truffle project, showing the error like - "  Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters:
    - host       > 127.0.0.1
    - port       > 7545
    - network_id > *
Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" or "--http" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)
   "

Comment: @SlaxmiRaj what is your operating system. check your port 7545 maybe something else is running on that port, or change the port number ganache and add this new port to the truffle config